# Django Assign json to model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have this function:

```
# create a function to upload an object one to one given a json
def upload_object_values(model, json_values):
if json_values:
    # the json values contain key value that match to the model
    # use a copy to avoid runtime error dictionary changing size
    for json_value in json_values.copy():
        # remove all ids in model copy
        if json_value[-3:] == '_id' or json_value == 'id':
            json_values.pop(json_value)

    # copy the object values only
    # TODO: ASSIGN json_values to the model object
    # save
    # model.save()
```

sample json_values:

```
{'id': 1, 'notes': 'hello', 'name': 'world', 'phone': None, 'foreign_id': 2}
```

sample cleanedjson_values (removed id and foreign keys):

```
{'notes': 'hello', 'name': 'world', 'phone': None}
```

How do I assign these values to the model that I have with each key being a field with the same name in my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
for key, value in json_values.items():
    setattr(model, key, value)
model.save()
```

Comment: I have a [follow-up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72693599/filter-django-model-with-json-values). I hope you may be able to answer it as well, thanks.